# SSRS on secondary server. Replication vs. Mirror vs. Always on vs.?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2022

We are deploying a new instance of SQL (2022), coming from SQL 2014. We want to provide SSRS for reporting, but do not want run these against the live database. Even after watching https://youtu.be/mxz-QXNoYgo I am getting lost between Replication, Always On, Mirroring, and so on. Which scenario should we be looking at to run SSRS on a secondary server so that report queries aren't slowing down our applications?

Comment: To be clear, you want to copy your user databases to a second server for reporting purposes?...The SSRS instance itself and system databases you're only keeping in one place?